# Return a function with an arbitrary number of input parameters

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, runnable

My code needs to pre-check a series of complex regex via various helper classes.
Then, it needs to execute a series of function calls in a post-check fashion if all is ok. If the case construct doesn't catch something I need to log it for later.

I am trying to avoid having two honking great duplicated `if` statements.

I was thinking, if the big `if` statement (or `switch`) were to return a function, I could check whether that returned function was null or not to do the pre-check. If it were null, I could also log it. If it weren't null, I could call it directly. This way I can do away with the need to have the complex logic checking in two parts of the code.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
class Playground {
    public static Function getFunction(String condition) {
        switch (condition) {
            case "one":
                return Function one(1);
            case "two":
                return Function two("two",2);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    public static void one(int i) {
        System.out.println("one: i: " + i);
    }

    public static void two(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println("two: s: " + s + " i: " + i);
    }
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
       Function f1 = getFunction("one");
       Function f2 = getFunction("two");
       f1();
       f2();
    }
}
```

But I can't quite get the syntax right.

Can someone tell me if this is feasible in Java? If so, perhaps someone can advise on the syntax corrections.

- All method called will have void return.
- They'll be instance calls rather than static methods.
- The function returned may have a differing number of input parameters. When the method gets invoked I need to somehow set that up as well.

If there is no such way, is there an alternative, perhaps a design pattern, that might help? (Other than mapping the complex if statement to something like an integer. If nothing is matched it's 0, otherwise you have values. Then you'd have another switch based on the int.)

Comment: Is [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) an option?

Comment: I could do that too - but at that point I would tend to go with two case constructs -the first part that does the checking involves about 50 permutations - each with possible regexes. So it's quite a computationally intensive selection process, and quite involved.so mapping that to an integer is probably a cleaner approach than reflection. My goal is to reduce complexity and keep maintenance as easy as possible.

Comment: @Abra - that is where my naivety on the syntax has crept in... Have been reviewing Youtube videos on things like Predicate, Function, Supplier and Consumer.. to try and improve my understanding.

Comment: Once you retrieve the method, you need to invoke it, don't you? How do you know the number and types of the arguments that you need to supply in order to invoke the method?

Comment: I had rather hoped the item being returned as a function would have been constructed with all the items it needed to just call directly - encapsulation wished for but perhaps not provided by Java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to return a Runnable that calls a method:

```
class Playground{
    public static Runnable getRunnable(String condition) {
        switch (condition) {
            case "one":
                return () -> one(1);
            case "two":
                return () -> two("two", 2);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    public static void one(int i) {
        System.out.println("one: i: " + i);
    }

    public static void two(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println("two: s: " + s + " i: " + i);
    }
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
       Runnable f1 = getRunnable("one");
       Runnable f2 = getRunnable("two");
       Runnable f3 = getRunnable("three");
       f1.run();
       f2.run();
       if (f3 == null) {
           System.out.println("none");
       }
    }
}
```